# Optimizing jQuery function for nth-child of long list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that I need to repeat 20 times for a long list of elements.

It looks like this:

```
jQuery("#post-selected-container .tablerow:eq(0)").css({'height':(jQuery(".tablerow.center:eq(0)").height()+'px')});
jQuery("#post-selected-container-two .tablerow:eq(0)").css({'height':(jQuery(".tablerow.center:eq(0)").height()+'px')});

jQuery("#post-selected-container .tablerow:eq(1)").css({'height':(jQuery(".tablerow.center:eq(1)").height()+'px')});
jQuery("#post-selected-container-two .tablerow:eq(1)").css({'height':(jQuery(".tablerow.center:eq(1)").height()+'px')});

jQuery("#post-selected-container .tablerow:eq(2)").css({'height':(jQuery(".tablerow.center:eq(2)").height()+'px')});
jQuery("#post-selected-container-two .tablerow:eq(2)").css({'height':(jQuery(".tablerow.center:eq(2)").height()+'px')});
(...)
```

Any chance I can optimize and use less code for it? It goes until element 20...

Comment: the .css() method can accept a function. http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-function note the example below it that has access to both the current element and it's index, so, yes, you certainly can do what you're doing with less actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    var h = jQuery(".tablerow.center:eq(" + i + ")").height() + 'px';

    jQuery("#post-selected-container .tablerow:eq(" + i + ")").css({ 'height': h });
    jQuery("#post-selected-container-two .tablerow:eq(" + i + ")").css({ 'height': h });
}
```

Comment: please share your reasoning along with the down-vote, thus everyone can benefit from learning what's wrong here and the better way of doing this